# select specific Columns with createQueryBuilder in Doctrine ORM using Parameters

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select("p.$input")
    ->from('AppBundle:Profile', 'p')
    ->where("p.$input LIKE :value")
    ->setParameter('value', '%'.$value.'%')
    ->setMaxResults(5);

$results = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
$response['results'] = $results;
```

is there a way to even set the `$input` using setParameter ?

Comment: Why do you need to use setParameter() ? The select() method accepts a string. You can format it before in any way you prefer, with sprintf() ou whatever way to prefer if it outputs a string.

Comment: @MeuhMeuh thanks for the comment , the reason is the property to be selected from the Entity will be decided by a user entered string. While I have the option to sanitize it, I prefer to use the parameter binding .

Comment: Indeed, I think that there is no way to do this in Doctrine. There is a Connection::quote() method but only sanitizing values and not column names. Instead, what about whitelisting some column names ? Don't you have the columns names list somewhere ? It would be way more secure.

Comment: Also, it makes me think that without knowing how your workflow is designed, it's generally unsafe to strictly bind interface shown names to strict column names. You definitely should make it more abstract in your UI if you consider that the user input is unsafe. Describing your table columns and permitting the users to interact directly with them is generally not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this in that way:

```
class EntityHelper{
    /**
     * @param Object $entity
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public static function entityToArray($entity) {
        $className = "\0" . get_class($entity) . "\0";
        $entityAsArray = (array)$entity;
        $retArray = array();
        foreach ($entityAsArray as $key => $val) {
            $retArray[str_replace($className, '', $key)] = $val;
        }
        return $retArray;
    }

    /**
     * @param Object $entity
     * @param string $parameter
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function checkEntityHasParameter($entity, $parameter) {
        return array_key_exists($parameter, self::entityToArray($entity));
    }
}
```

Use **checkEntityHasParameter** static method to check that field will occur in your table.

**WARNING!** It works only with standard type fields, and sometimes when mapping were used.